# d3plus.Geomap is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I am making my first d3plus chart and trying to copy one in here
https://d3plus.org/examples/d3plus-geomap/coordinate-points/

But unlike highcharts there is very little explanation on how to use the chart.
My current code is:

```
<script src="./d3plus.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"> </div>

<script>

new d3plus.Geomap()
  .container("#viz")
  .data("https://d3plus.org/data/city_coords.json")
  .groupBy("slug")
  .colorScale("dma_code")
  .colorScaleConfig({
    color: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
  })
  .label(function(d) {
    return d.city + ", " + d.region;
  })
  .point(function(d) {
    return [d.longitude, d.latitude];
  })
  .render();


  </script>
```

---

and I am getting error : d3plus.Geomap is not a constructor.
Can some please tell me my mistake or point me towards basic d3plus examples

Comment: You need to reference the proper d3plus perhaps try https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-geomap.v0.6.full.min.js, then after that you have an answer regarding the container.  You are right, the examples should actually show the library in the code and how to utilize that.

Comment: Note it looks like the examples my have been updated since you posted this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container()` method is deprecated in v2 of `d3plus`

Instead, you must using `select("#viz")`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ctkujr2/

Comment: Good information however this is NOT the crux of the OPs actual error message - which you have resolved in your fiddle by actually using the correct library code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the proper version of the library - and from my perspective the documentation lacks in this areas.

THIS FAILS

```js
new d3plus.Geomap()

  .data("https://d3plus.org/data/city_coords.json")
  .groupBy("slug")
  .colorScale("dma_code")
  .colorScaleConfig({
color: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
  })
  .label(function(d) {
return d.city + ", " + d.region;
  })
  .point(function(d) {
return [d.longitude, d.latitude];
  })
  .render();
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3plus/1.9.8/d3plus.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="viz"> </div>
```

**THIS WORKS**

```js
new d3plus.Geomap()
  .data("https://d3plus.org/data/city_coords.json")
  .groupBy("slug")
  .colorScale("dma_code")
  .colorScaleConfig({
color: ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
  })
  .label(function(d) {
return d.city + ", " + d.region;
  })
  .point(function(d) {
return [d.longitude, d.latitude];
  })
  .render();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-geomap.v0.6.full.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This work, but how? We have not specified a container() or select() method.

Comment: "By default, d3plus will render visualizations in a new SVG element appended to the end of page body." ref: https://d3plus.org/examples/d3plus-hierarchy/selecting-container/  - you CAN have the `select` if you need it.  The point here is that the actual library is your issue, NOT the `select/container` given the error you received.